# C programming : If I put integer into a char array, then what is the type of the number that is printed?

Tags: c

this is my code :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main()
{
    char array[50];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 50)
    {
        array[i] = rand();
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so I generate pseudo-random numbers and put them into array but my array is char and what I put in is integer. So why can I be able to use %d? I thought %d tells printf that array[i] is a 4-byte integer and printf should convert into string. but array[i] is char not int. Can someone explain this to me please.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `"%s"` and `"%c"`? If not read up on it. It migth already answer your question.

Comment: sidenote: Use `srand(time(NULL));` at the begin of your `main()` if you want to get different numbers everytime the program gets executed. And it's `int main(void)` in C.

Comment: thank you @Yunnosch. I just edit my question for more clarification

Comment: `char` is synonym to "(possibly) smaller than `short int` int"

Comment: Parameters of variadic functions are undergoing default promotions. To `int` in your case.

Comment: Read up on argument promotion and varargs functions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions

Comment: `array[i] = rand()` puts 8 bits worth of `rand()` into your array. But then passing `array[i]` as a parameter to `printf()` expands it to an int.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is variadic argument function. This means you can pass it any number of arguments, and then the function needs to have a way to figure out what they are. `printf` does this using the first argument, format string, which must match the other arguments.

Now, when you pass any shorter integer as variadic argument, it gets promoted to `int` type. Same with unsigned types. This happens with `char`, it gets promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`, depending on platform). Another example is `float` getting promoted to `double`, which is why you don't have format for printing `float`, `%f` also prints a `double` (check docs if in doubt).

This means for `printf`, that `%c` format actually uses an `int` value (or unsigned depending on platform), and therefore you can print it with `%d` without issues (assuming `char` is signed on your platform).

On some platforms, where `char` is unsigned, and if you have compiler warnings enabled, you will actually get a warning, trying to print unsigned value with `%d`, which could (in this case *very* theoretically, but still) cause funny things due to *Undefined Behavior*.